# Installing MATLAB 2016a onto ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, matlab

Hey I recently built a computer and put ubuntu 16.04 onto it. Now I'm going through and adding different software packages. One of them that I got is MATLAB 2016a which I have no idea how to install on a Linux system. I've really never used one before so please excuse the learning curve. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to go about doing this?

I have the downloaded the zip file but I can't seem to extract the file. That seem to be the portion I'm stuck on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the instructions for Linux at http://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/install-mathworks-software.html.

Answer (score 6):

1. If `unzip` command isn't already installed in your system, run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unzip
   ```
2. Go to the directory you downloaded Matlab .zip file:

   ```
   cd /path/to/download/directory
   ```
3. Unzip the file:

   ```
   unzip downloaded_matlab_zip_file.zip -d matlab_destination_directory
   ```
4. Navigate to `matlab_destination_directory`:

   ```
   cd matlab_destination_directory
   ```
5. Run the Matlab installer:

   ```
   ./install
   ```
6. Follow [these](http://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/install-mathworks-software.html) installation steps from the vendor.

Comment: Alright thank you. I was a bit lost but was  able to get the installation going with these instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Important hint: The MATLAB installation wizard may get stuck creating the installation directory (by default `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a`) because it does not have enough write permissions. If that happens, the easy solution is to run the Matlab installer as a super user

```
sudo ./install
```

A useful post regarding this issue in particular is here:
[How to get permissions to a folder in an installation process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481481/how-to-get-permissions-to-a-folder-in-an-installation-process)