# Installing MATLAB onto ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, matlab

I having problem while installing Matlab. I was trying Matlab from my institute networks.

I downloaded zip file and extracted on local computer.

Then I navigated to that folder. these are my commands:

```
safir@safir:~/matlab/linux$ sudo ./install 
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Finished
safir@safir:~/matlab/linux$
```

But not installed. I cant find matlab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing MATLAB 2016a onto ubuntu 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/823778/installing-matlab-2016a-onto-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that you can't find MATLAB? What output do you get when you run `whereis matlab`?

Comment: safir@safir:~$ whereismatlab
whereismatlab: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - installer finishes without doing anything.

Cause: I had mounted a .iso file of the DVD, copied everything over and attempted to run the installer from the copied files. That doesn't work.

You must run the installer from the DVD or from the mounted .iso.